# How do I specify my own data values in Django REST framework JWT?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I want to keep full_name and username in the JSON web token. I need some help with overriding the jwt_payload_handler.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt) you just need this:

```
>>> import jwt
>>> payload = {'user_full_name': 'Some Awesome Name'}
>>> encoded = jwt.encode(payload, 'secret', algorithm='HS256')
'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzb21lIjoicGF5bG9hZCJ9.4twFt5NiznN84AWoo1d7KO1T_yoc0Z6XOpOVswacPZg'

>>> jwt.decode(encoded, 'secret', algorithms=['HS256'])
{'user_full_name': 'Some Awesome Name'}
```

Comment: I am here using JWT with DRF using https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt. Can you help in that context?